# Laravel 5.4 relationship between two tables and ORM request

Tags: php, laravel, orm, request

I'm making a search bar, I have a problem in the request with ORM Laravel ...

Their is my models :

```
 class Ville extends Model
{
    public function house() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\House');
    }
}

class House extends Model {
    public function ville() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ville');
    }
}
```

House table has an "id_ville". I'm searching for the request with ORM like :

```
public function index()
{
    $search = \Request::get('search');
    $houses = house::where('ville_nom', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    return view('home')->with('houses', $houses);
}
```

but I can't see anything in the template ..

Answer (score 0):

Check the Docs, namely the section about **Defining the Inverse Relationship** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

There, you'll see this:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id. However, if the foreign key on the Phone model is not user_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method:

Since your key is *prefixed* with id instead of *suffixed*, you'll need to update your relationship to explicitly specify the FK.

Comment: Yes i agree with that, Eloquent determines that House belongs to Ville because the models + the FK ville_id.
My problem is in my request 
        $houses = house::where('ville_nom', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');

Comment: $search here is the values of input send to Controllerù

Comment: If you suspect there's something wrong with the ORM query, enable the log to double check the ORM is creating the correct query https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging.  However, I still am suspicious of the definition of your model.  You say in your comment the key is 'ville_id' but in your question you say it's 'id_ville' .  Also, it is unclear whether 'ville_nom' belongs to House or Ville.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not strictly following the primary and foreign keys **Eloquent** conventions, you can easily specify your own:

```
class House extends Model {
    public function ville() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ville::class, 'id_ville');
    }
}
```

And here is a way to retrieve houses by searching for a Ville.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $houses = House::whereHas('ville', function ($query) {
        $query->where('ville_nom', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search .'%');
    })->get();
    return view('home')->with('houses', $houses);
}
```